# ¿Cómo pasar parámetros de un componente a un modal en Angular 4?

Tags: angular2-template

Estoy editando un registro de una lista, al darle clic me abre este registro en un modal con información del usuario a editar, hasta allí todo bien.

Mi inconveniente es que dentro del modal estoy cargando un servicio que depende del usuario seleccionado, esta función la ejecuto en el `OnInit` del modal pero como el modal carga en mi componente principal cuando abro el modal ese servicio esta vacío ya que se ejecuto al cargar el componente principal y no al cargar el modal.

**¿Cómo podría hacer para que mi función se ejecute cuando abro el modal y no cuando carga el componente?**

**Nota:** el modal esta en un componente y mi listado de registros en otro componente

**Template principal:**

```
 <app-modal modalId="editUser" modalSize="modal-lg" modalTitle="Editar Usuario - {{user.userId}}" modalIcon="ion-ios-person-outline">
  <app-edit-user [user]="user"></app-edit-user>
</app-modal>
```

**Component principal** (desde aquí llamo mi modal):

```
 onRowSelect(event) {
   this.newUser = false;
   this.user = this.cloneUser(event.data);
   $("#editUser").modal();
  }
```

**Component Modal**

```
  getParameters(user){
    console.log(user);
    this._userService.getParameter(user).subscribe(
      response => {
      this.userParameter = response.pagedResult.resultado;
      console.log(this.userParameter);
    }, 
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    );
  }

 // Desde aqui llamo la función pero como se ejecuta al cargar el componente los datos siempre vienen vacios

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.user.userId);
    this.getParameters(this.user.userId);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea es utilizar el ngOnChanges en tu componente que hace de edit user y en tu componente de listado recoge el componente edit user component y le pasas el dato antes de llamarlo.

> ModalComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: `
    <div [hidden]="hidden">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ModalComponent {

  hidden = true;

  open() {
    this.hidden = false;
  }

  close() {
    this.hidden = true;
  }

}
```

> EditUserComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-user',
  template: `
    <form (onSubmit)="onSubmit() [hidden]="!user || !userParameter">
      <!-- tus campos... -->
    </form>
  `
})
export class EditUserComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() user = null;
  userParameter = null;
  @Output() onResult = new EventEmitter<any>(null);

  constructor(private userService: UserService)

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes['user']) {
      this.userService.getParameter(changes.user.currentValue).subscribe(
        userParameter => this.userParameter = userParameter
      );
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // ...
    const user = ...;
    // ...
    this.userService.updat(user).subscribe(
      (userEdited) => this.onResult.emmit({ hasErrors: true, user: userEdited }),
      (err) => this.onResult.emmit({ hasErrors: true, user: user })
    );
  }

}
```

> UsersComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let user of users" (click)="onClickUser(user)">
        #{{ user.id }} - {{ user.name }} {{ user.lastname }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <app-modal>
      <app-edit-user (onResult)="onUserEdited($event)"></app-edit-user>
    </app-modal>
  `
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  users = [];
  @ViewChild(ModalComponent) modalComponent: ModalComponent;
  @ViewChild(EditUserComponent) editUserComponent: EditUserComponent;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getAll().subscribe(users => this.users = users);
  }

  onClickUser(user) {
    this.editUserComponent.user = user;
    this.modalComponent.open();
  }

  onUserEdited($event) {
    if ($event.hasErrors) {
      console.error(`Error al editar el usuario`);
    } else {
      const index = this.users.findIndex(user => user.id === $event.user.id);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.users[index] = $event.user;
      }
    }
    this.modalComponent.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Voy aprobarlo y te cuento de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Gracias hermano, me funciono!!